# Refer child model in parent model in DBT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, dbt-cloud

Below is my data flow in DBT

```
publisher_DB_view ->(incremental pull)-> Raw_tbl ->(appends)-> stg_tbl
```

The requirement is that Raw table should pull only the records incrementally from publisher_DB_view where publisher_DB_view .date_id > stg_tbl.date_id. To resolve this i am refering to stg_tbl.date_id inside where clause of raw_tbl.date_id like below .

```
raw_tbl.sql

{{config(materialized='table')}}
select * 
from {{ref('external_db_view')}}
where date_id > ( select max(date_id) from {{ref('stg_tbl)}})
--------------------------------------------------------------

stg_tbl.sql

{{config(materialized='incremental',unique_key='date_id')}}
select * 
from {{ref('raw_tbl')}}
```

My model fails with uncaught exception while parsing. I assume this is because of DAG nature so a child model can not be referenced back in parent model . I tried implementing this by creating a macro / pre_hook to get max(date_id) from stg_tbl and then use in raw_tbl however it also fails with same parsing error . i checked by referring to another model (independent) and then model succeeds)

Is this a real limitation in DBT and if so , is there any work around to get this done ? Thanks in advance for answering !

Comment: Can you please add the uncaught exception you mentioned?

Answer (score 2):

In the example you use,

- in model `raw_tbl` , `raw_tbl` depends on `stg_tbl`
- in model `stg_tbl`, it depends on `raw_tbl` again

This leads to a circular dependency, which breaks so called DAG directed acyclic  graph. And DAG is a mandatory requirement, otherwise it will cause an infinite loop.

In your example, I can recommend use two separate stages of incremental models. Each model is independent from each other, but only depends on itself `{{ this }}` .

raw_tbl.sql

```
{{config(materialized='incremental')}}
select * 
from {{ref('external_db_view')}}
where date_id > ( select max(date_id) from {{ this }})
```

stg_tbl.sql

```
{{config(materialized='incremental',unique_key='date_id')}}
select * 
from {{ref('raw_tbl')}}  
where date_id > ( select max(date_id) from {{ this }})
```

Comment: Yes , this DAG explanation also came to my understanding. I infect tried it implementing the same thing via macro but even then it fails... Kind of a Proof of understanding ... Thanks.

Comment: Great to see it helps @PawanRawat. The cyclic dependency is quite hard to catch specially when circular is formed via a long path. With a lineage visually will be much easy to spot.

Answer (score 0):

If `Raw_tbl` is not needed, then `stg_tbl` can be changed to look like dbt's [documentation](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/incremental-models#filtering-rows-on-an-incremental-run) suggestion:

```
select * 
from {{ref('external_db_view')}}

{% if is_incremental() %}

-- this filter will only be applied on an incremental run
-- (uses > to include records whose timestamp occurred since the last run of this model)
where date_id > ( select max(date_id) from {{ this }}))

{% endif %}
```